# How to turn off caching of jar file for Java applications on MacOs?

Tags: java, caching, jar

I have written an application in Java that runs on MacOS (Macbook Air, 12.6 Monterey, M1 processor). I use the jpackage tool to pack the jar into a dmg file that can be installed/run on MacOS (currently using the x64 Java 17/JavaFX 17 runtimes in my build). I use the xcrun altool to notorize the application for mac.

When my users are running the application there seem to be a lot of disc writes which I prefer not to have if possible (as do my users). Users can specify where the user data is stored and if they set that to another drive, the application still writes to the main drive (SSD). After a lot of trying out tools to see what is actually written even when the application does nothing, I found that it seems to contineous writing some kind of jar caching. (Folder: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ and then in a sub folder periodically jar_cach.tmp files.)

I have searched the internet but the only information I could find was how to remove the cached files (and if it is safe to do so) but that is not what I am looking for because the writes have already been done. I always thought that jar caches would only change when you are actually rewriting the jar file but my application does not rewrite the jar in the user environment (like when devving the application it would with every rewrite of the code) and the jar is obfuscated as well so that also does not imply changes to it during runtime in a user environment.

I hope this has given enough information about how it is set up for you to get an idea for a solution on the question below.

My question is there a way to turn off this cache writing either through some options I can set in my app (java code) or command line parameters (vm options) or a setting in Java itself that can turn it off? Or am I missing something else in my process which causes this seemingly unnecessary disc writes?